# Add long sleep to php page

Tags: php, sleep, nginx-config

I have a PHP page which needs to load slowly.

So I wrote something like:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(300);

$sdt = gmdate('Y-m-d h:i:s \G\M\T', time());
if (isset($_GET['sleep'])) {
    // Delays for xxx seconds.
    sleep( intval($_GET['sleep']) );
} 
$edt = gmdate('Y-m-d h:i:s \G\M\T', time());
echo $sdt . PHP_EOL;
echo $edt . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Unfortunately, after 60 seconds I get "404 Not Found nginx/1.20.0"

I need help in order to add sleep up to 300 seconds

Riccardo

Comment: Please share more details. Why do you need that? Nobody wants to wait five **minutes** for a response on your website

Comment: This is not a production server. It's a telco network test automation scenario. I'm using a tool which connects an android phone to UMTS, then it opens a website and finally closes the radio connection. But I need more time in order to test the Core Network. At the moment this is the only workaround that I found

Comment: This does not sound like anything a webserver should handle - why not use some AJAX- or WSS-based approach for this, which should avoid any problems with long-running PHP scripts?

Comment: Just because that tool does not handle javascript.

Comment: Use a socket server for this, not a web server: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-server.php  Or, even bbetter, not use php at all, but a tiny, specific socket server for exactly this purpose. Python sounds like a good base for such thing. Or, since you most likely have a unixoid system as backend, you can simply use `netcat` for this. Check the man page for details.

Answer (score 2):

To increase the time. It is necessary to increase the php running time, as well as the waiting time for the nginx response

PHP
In your code or php.ini

```
 set_time_limit(0);
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

NGINX

```
http{
   ...
   fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
   proxy_read_timeout 300;
   proxy_connect_timeout 300;
   proxy_send_timeout 300;
   ...
}
```

Comment: there is something additional.in php fpm pool config `request_terminate_timeout = 300`,and fastcgi config in nginx `fastcgi_read_timeout 300`.this really annonying while use xdebug to php

Comment: @nay Yes, there are really many config settings for exucute timing

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm. {
  "sleep": "240",
  "start-date": "2021-07-09 09:57:52 GMT",
  "end-date": "2021-07-09 10:01:52 GMT"
}